# HTML5 audio: trying to make a queue

Tags: javascript, html, audio, queue

I am working on a text-to-speech generator using JavaScript and html5 audio elements. The idea is to transform a string of IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) into sound. So in the function `talk()`, I take the string and split it. I then put the corresponding sounds into the `queue`, which I try to play with the `playQ(q)` function.

But that function doesn't seem to work. I can only make it play the first sound. So `q[0].play;` is working, but the rest of the `playQ(q)` function is not.

I'm thinking it is either because of the `q.shift()` method, but I have also tried `q[1:]`, or because of the recursivity.

```
function talk(){
    var queue = []
    var str = document.IPATTS.phonetic.value
    var letters = str.split("")
    for (x in letters) {
        queue.push(document.getElementById(letters[x]))
    }
    playQ(queue);
}

function playQ(q){
    q[0].play();
    var z = q.shift();
    q[0].onended = function() {playQ(z)};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As described [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift),

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

So with `var z = q.shift()` you are assigning `z = q[0]`
Also, `q[0]` will have a different value before and after `q.shift()`

I think this way it should work:

```
function playQ(q){
    q[0].play();
    q[0].onended = function() {
        q.shift();
        playQ(q);
    //  ^^^^^^^^^
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! Got it to work using

```
var z = []
for (x in q) {
    if (x > 0) {
        z.push(q[x])
    }
}
```

in stead of `var z = q.shift();`